# Bouncing Ball program Would like ball to reappear at top and come down again

Tags: iphone

Right now in my program the ball bounces up and down on the Y axis.  What i want is for the ball to only move in the downward direction. when it gets to the bottom of the screen I want it to reappears at the top and starts down again. Continually moving from top to bottom.

```
@implementation BounceViewController
@synthesize ball;

-(void) bounce{

    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x+position.x, ball.center.y+position.y); {

        if(ball.center.y>450 ||ball.center.y <0)
            position.y = -position.y; }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    position = CGPointMake(0, 10);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(bounce) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
        [self setBall:nil];
        [super viewDidUnload];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

in your bounce method replace the lines

```
if(ball.center.y>450 ||ball.center.y <0)
            position.y = -position.y;
```

with

```
if(ball.center.y>450 ||ball.center.y <0)
      ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x+position.x, position.y);
```